# Image download/save through QFileDialog

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qfiledialog

I searched but I can't find a solution, have pity on me. I want to download an Image and through QFileDialog from PyQt5 decide where to save.

First I download the file with module requests:

```
url = 'https://landscape.jpg'
r = requests.get(url)
image = r.content
```

... and then the other part of the code, QFileDialog:

```
options = QFileDialog.Options()
options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self,"Save Image","H:\Image","All Files (*)",options=options)
```

Where do I place the image variable in the QFileDialog statement?

Comment: As eyllanesc points out (below) QFileDialog does not save files but it can give you more than just a filename it can also return the path of a directory that you can then use in your save operation to save the file.  But its main purpose is to give a user an interface that allows them to traverse the directory tree and you seem to already know where you want to put that file so you would have no need for QFileDialog.  In fact if you have no Gui associated with this then you would not need pyqt at all and could do all this from within straight python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`QFileDialog` is only a widget that allows you to obtain a filename and does not know how to save any file, what you should do is save it as any file using open() and write():

```
url = "https://landscape.jpg"
r = requests.get(url)
image = r.content

options = QFileDialog.Options()
options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(
    self, "Save Image", r"H:\Image", "All Files (*)", options=options
)

if fileName:
    with open(fileName, "wb") as f:
        f.write(image)
```

Comment: I am disappointed! What does that r mean in front of "H:\Image"? Thank you.

Comment: @Nepura raw string, read https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html for more information